# how to load contents inside body after jquery spinner loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display a jQuery Spinner while loading the page for a particular time. After loading the Spinner, the content inside the body tag should display. Only after completing the jQuery spinner.

I have tried and jQuery spinner is working, after that contents inside body is not displaying.

My code is,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        "use strict";
        var element = $('<div></div>').css({
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
        }).appendTo('body');

        element.canvasLoader({
            color: '#ff0000'
        });

        element.canvasLoader(false);

        element.canvasLoader(true);

        element.canvasLoader.options[0].color = '#008000';

        $(element).trigger('stop.canvasLoader');

        $(element).trigger('start.canvasLoader');

        $(element).trigger('destroy.canvasLoader');

        $.fn.canvasLoader.options.customOptionsSet = {
            color: '#ffff00'
        };

        $(element).canvasLoader('customOptionsSet');

        $.fn.canvasLoader.options.defaults.color = '#0000ff';

        $(element).data({
            canvasLoaderShape: 'rect',
            canvasLoaderColor: '#00ffff'
        }).canvasLoader('attr');

        $(element).css({
            'font-family': 'oval',
            'color': '#ff00ff',
            'line-height': '103px',
            'letter-spacing': '71px',
            'word-spacing': '.4px',
            'font-size': '2px',
            'text-indent': '26px'
        }).canvasLoader('css');

        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        $(element).canvasLoader({
            //start:deferred.promise()
            start: false
        }).canvasLoader(deferred.promise());
        setTimeout(deferred.resolve, 3000);
        //setTimeout(deferred.reject,3000);

        var version = $.fn.canvasLoader.version;

    });
</script>
```

Is there any method to do so?

JSFiddle Link is : http://jsfiddle.net/efhL2bxm/

Comment: can you provide JSfiddle.? to see actually happnes when your page loads

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara :- use this link `http://jsfiddle.net/efhL2bxm/`

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara :- Is there any other method?

Comment: i can't find out but i think you can use lazy loaders for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually displaying. Just change the `fontsize` for `body`. Currently `fontsize` is `2px` and hence it is not showing.